# Perl script shows different behavior inside cron job

Tags: perl, scripting, cron

I'm executing the following commands in a perl script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $MPSTAT="/usr/bin/mpstat";
my $GREP="/bin/grep";
my $FREE = "/usr/bin/free";
my $AWK = "/bin/awk";
my $cpu = `$MPSTAT | $GREP all | $AWK '{print (100 - \$12)}'`;
print "CPU is $cpu";
```

When I run this perl script manually it's getting executed properly and providing the proper *CPU Usage in % (100 - Idle CPU)*.

But when I execute it as a cronjob it always prints 100 & it appears that $12 of awk is getting the value of 0. Any pointers on why it's behaving differently in cron would be helpful.

Comment: Get rid of the `awk` statement and just print the entire output of `grep`.  Then you'll be able to see whether the input to `awk` is different from what you expect.

Comment: If you remove `my $`'s from this code, its valid shell code. It's a bad thing to write perl this way.

Comment: @jordanm yes, I agree. But here I have just copied a very tiny part of 900 lines perl script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main differences between running as a child of cron are:

1. The user ID might be different (root vs normal user)
2. The environment is nearly empty, at least pretty different

The second part often means that programs might output in a different language or number format due to the values of the `LANG` and `LC_*` environment variables which might be set for the normal user but not when run under cron (or vice versa).

Comment: But in my script I'm not dependent on any environment variables/user dependent.

Comment: Your script itself does not depend on them, but you're executing external programs which are. For example, "free" outputs "Größe" etc. for a German locale and "Size" for an English one. Same for time, date and number formats.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution using the hint provided by @WinnieNicklaus

mpstat is giving different results in cron.

**Normal Execution:**

```
04:53:18 PM  all   49.51    0.00    4.79    2.67    0.02    0.34    0.00    0.00   42.68
```

**Inside Cron:**

```
16:54:01   all   49.51    0.00    4.79    2.67    0.02    0.34    0.00    0.00   42.68
```

Since PM is not getting printed inside cron, when changed the argument for awk as $11 instead of $12 it started working.

Comment: And that difference is almost certainly due to different values of `$LANG` or `$LC_*` environment variables as pointed out by Moritz.